# adding columns to an existing table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to add around 600 columns to an existing table for testing purpose

```
declare @counter int
    set @counter = 1
    while @counter < 601
    begin

    ALTER TABLE Info ADD column+@counter varchar(max);
    set @counter = @counter + 1

    end
```

The column name should looks like column1,column2....column600

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is purely for testing a quick and dirty way is to do this:

```
declare @counter int
set @counter = 1
declare @sql varchar(2000)

while @counter < 601
begin

Set @Sql = 'ALTER TABLE Info ADD column'+convert(varchar(10),@counter)+ ' varchar(max)'
Exec (@Sql)
set @counter = @counter + 1

end
```

Although I have to wonder *why* you would want 600 columns in a table

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic sql execution-

```
SET @str = 'ALTER TABLE Info ADD column' + CAST(@counter as varchar(5)) + ' varchar(max)';
EXEC ( @str );
GO
```

Comment: A quick edit is required as you will need to explicitly convert `@counter` to a varchar for this to work :)

Comment: @Barry - yes. Thank you. Always forget that conversion for dynamic concat.

Answer (score 0):

use Exec function:

```
Declare @SQL VarChar(1000)
Declare @vary varchar(100)
Declare @final varchar(1000)

SELECT @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + @TableName
select @vary = 'add column ' + id
select @final = @sql + @vary

Exec ( @final)
GO
```