# How to add SUPER column to existing AWS Redshift table?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

**GOAL**

- I would like to add a Redshift SUPER [column](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_type.html) to and existing redshift table.
- I need this to store JSON data there

**CODE**

This is how Normally I would add a new column.

```
ALTER TABLE products 
ADD COLUMN created_at NOT NULL;
```

**1. Tried**

```
CREATE TABLE temp_test_persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);

ALTER TABLE temp_test_persons ADD COLUMN newSuperColumn SUPER NOT NULL;
```

### Error running query: ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN defined as NOT NULL must have a non-null default expression

**Reviewed Solutions**

- [Alter column data type in Amazon Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101918/alter-column-data-type-in-amazon-redshift)
- [AWS Redshift - Add IDENTITY column to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377165/aws-redshift-add-identity-column-to-existing-table)
- [Adding column to existing tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309840/adding-column-to-existing-tables)
- [Add dynamic column to existing MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417461/add-dynamic-column-to-existing-mysql-table)
- [SQLAlchemy: How to add column to existing table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271239/sqlalchemy-how-to-add-column-to-existing-table)
- [adding columns to an existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337182/adding-columns-to-an-existing-table)
- [add column to existing table postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667701/add-column-to-existing-table-postgres)
- [How to add not null unique column to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052368/how-to-add-not-null-unique-column-to-existing-table)
- [Adding columns to existing csv file using super-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284026/adding-columns-to-existing-csv-file-using-super-csv)
- [UCanAccess: Add column to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143741/ucanaccess-add-column-to-existing-table)
- [Adding columns to existing redshift table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886271/adding-columns-to-existing-redshift-table)
- [How to add column to existing table in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58553497/how-to-add-column-to-existing-table-in-laravel)
- [Add column to existing table in rds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63394107/add-column-to-existing-table-in-rds)
- [oracle add column to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194442/oracle-add-column-to-existing-table)

Comment: Did you try simply adding the datatype to your statement? `ALTER TABLE products ADD COLUMN newSuperColumn SUPER NOT NULL;`

Comment: I have tried but it gave back an error (as yo can see it above in my edited post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE temp_test_persons 
ADD COLUMN newSuperColumn SUPER;
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set a default value for the column. Then you can define the column as NotNull.
Like this

```
ALTER TABLE temp_test_persons 
ADD COLUMN newSuperColumn SUPER NOT NULL 
DEFAULT '';
```